# failed to start service

Tags: systemd, services

I have created a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/sh $HOME/theFolder/run.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=mine.service
```

I put it in the /etc/systemd/system folder and named it mine.service.

If I run `sudo service mine start` it gives me :

> Failed to start mine.service.Unit mine.service not found

--- UPDATE -----

I run first `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and now it doesn't give me any messages but the service still doesn't start.

Comment: Have you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after creating your unit file?

Comment: @Wieland:Hmm..Now it doesn't show me any messages.But,it still doesn't start.

Comment: @don_crissti:The status says it is active ,but the script ( in ExecStart ) is not executed.

Comment: how it would know the proper $HOME? What you expect it to be for a system service?

Comment: @Serge:Hmm..So, how can I use $HOME?

Comment: Which one? if you are creating a user service then it should be installed in a different way. please read the docs https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User

Comment: @Serge:I will read.I mean the standar home folder. /home/user.

Answer (score 16):

`$HOME` points to the user's home directory who is running the script. Systemd services are started with root so it will likely trying to `/root/theFolder/run.sh`. Use absolute paths in service files.

You also have the `forking` option set. This is needed for program that background themselves, does your script do this? Most do not and if yours does not you should remove this option or systemd will be waiting for your script to finish to claim it as started.

Also system service files that point to scripts in your home directory are discouraged and possibly a security concern. Since they are run as root anyone that can modify them can potentially gain root access to your computer. It is far better to copy the script to `/usr/local/bin` and ensure it is owned and only writable by root to stop this. It is also a good idea to run the script as an unprivileged user using the `User=` and `Group=` options in the service file.

If you want to run it as your user it is better to put the service file in `~/.config/systemd/user/` and start/enable it with `systemctl --user enable yourservice && systemctl --user start yourservice` (note, run as your user not root). See [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) for more info on user service files.

Comment: :I put the script into /usr/local/bin and the service into /.config/systemd/user.If I try to enable the service ,it shows me "excess arguments".If I try to use systemctl it shows 'failed.. unit..',something like this.

Comment: Can you provide the full commands you tried and more detailed logs. Its hard to debug with fragments.

Comment: :Is there a solution to use the $HOME path?Because,if I put the script in /usr/local/bin ,it uses relative paths to $HOME.I saw [this](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/10474/why-systemd-is-not-loading-environment-file/).And I tried to put `HOME=$HOME` in the first environment file.But the service couldn't start,no errors.

Comment: You need to run it as your user if you require $HOME to be configured correctly (and also to stop root owned files appearing in your home directory). Note that if you use the user service file method you don't need to copy the script to /usr/local/bin, that is just for system scripts.

Comment: :Do you mean run it as `sudo systemd --user start service`?

Comment: With out `sudo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42054/discussion-between-george-and-michael-daffin).

Comment: I got this error when using environment variables in my service file: `EnvironmentFile=/etc/profile.d/pipeline_envvars.sh
 +ExecStart=${APP_VIRTUALENV}/bin/python /project/python/daemons/myjob.py`. it the systemd manual it says it should work but does not.  My envvars file contains 1 line, `APP_VIRTUALENV=/path/to/venv`. I get ` Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-01-25 19:49:39 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 3190 ExecStart=/${APP_VIRTUALENV}/bin/python /project/python/daemons/myjob.py (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)`. Swapping the env var with the actual path works

Comment: So I see in syslog, `Failed at step EXEC spawning /${APP_VIRTUALENV}/bin/python: No such file or directory` but if I echo out the env var in the ExecStart I see echo: `/path/to/env` which looks good and the dir does exist. It may have something to do with trying to instantiate multiple instances :(

Comment: Not sure if you can use environment variables in the exec line - try the absolute path and see if that works.

Comment: on ubuntu I had to use systemctl for this not systemd, using systemd I got an error "Excess Arguments"

Comment: @AlexanderMills You are right, the correct command in systemctl and systemd was just a typo in the answer.